# How to hide pop-up with docs information on hover atributes tag in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The annoying pop-up on hover inline css properties
I tried to found out where is it in the Settings, but i could not find something that will help me. It distracted me from work and i felt sad and irritated. For a few days i looked for the solution of this problem but to no avail
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aEbF.png)